# Slope between max and min values of a defined area within a DEM

Tags: arcpy, lidar, 3d-analyst, terrain

Say I have a DEM raster.  I then also I have a set of polygons in which I would like to know the slope between the max and min DEM values of any given polygon.  If my thinking is correct, I could calculate the max slope as follows...

from within any given polygon:

(maxElev - minElev) / distance(maxElevPoint, minElevPoint)

I think the math is correct, but what tools within 3D Analyst could help me to automate this.  I can Python and know ArcPy, but I'm not sure where to start.  I found the Slope tool that deals with rasters within the 3D Analyst extension,  I could convert to raster but from what I can tell this gives the slope back for each cell compared to it's adjacent cells.

what is the best workflow for doing this type of analysis?

Comment: When trying to figure out a new workflow I always think the best place to start is with some test code. Work from what you know to what you don't and ask about where you get stuck.

Comment: Your math is wrong. What makes you think it give you max slope. Slope raster is a way to go

Comment: @FelixIP Can you please explain how the math is wrong?

Comment: I am not interested in finding the slope between adjacent cells.  I.E. I don't want a raster output in which each cell is given the max slope value of its adjacent cells.  I want the maximum slope of the portion of the raster contained by each polygon.

Comment: Slope 1 / 1 is bigger than 50/100, i.e. largest difference in elevation does not always produce greatest slope

Comment: Slope is defined as the rise/run.  In your examples you are saying a vertical change of 1 unit divided by a horizontal change of 1 unit.  This indicates a 45 degree incline.  50 unit rise divided by 100 unit run would indicate a 26.56 degree incline.  So...  I'm not disputing how fractions work and are evaluated.  I still don't understand how the math in the OP is wrong?  I'm working on coding this now.  Hopefully I will have something to add in the next day or two.

Comment: I think he means that if the 2nd maxElev point is much more close to the minElev point than the 1st maxElev point is, then the slope between the 2nd maxElev point and the minElev point will be greater than the 1st maxElev point and the minElev point (it will be greater than you are calling 'max slope' by using max and min elevation). Suppose the 1st maxElev point (a) is 100 meter, 2nd maxElev point (b) is 90 meter and minElev point (c) is 50 meter. Now, suppose the distance between 'a' and 'c' is 1000 meter and between 'b' and 'c' is 50 meter. Which one gives greatest slope? (/cc @FelixIP)

Comment: @FelixIP and Andre Silva.  Okay, yes that makes sense.  In the code I posted below it accounts for this by considering the max slope to be between the pairs of min/max values that are the furthest distance from each other.  So.. The algorithm goes as follows.  Identify the min and max values from the set,  get the coordinates of each point that is either a min or max value, determine which set of min/max value points are the farthest apart, do the math for slope/angle/difference etc.  Does this make sense for trying to establish the max overall slope for the specified area?

Comment: Use itertools and compute slope for combination of all points by 2

Answer (score 2):

I truly struggle to understand your definition of slope and believe slope derived drom DEM is the one you need. Alternatively you might apply TIN and take a slope of steepest triangle.

However If you insist on your definition of slope, considering 2 extreme points to derive the highest slope is wrong. Let's assume for simplicity that you have only 4 points sitting on a straight line:

[image]

Isn't it obvious, that highest slope is not between points 1,4 (your extremes!), but between points 2 and 3? Thus you'll need to iterate between all combinations of points' pairs. Good luck with this, knowing density of LiDAR points...

SOLUTION BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION, assumes points have PGON_ID assigned:

```
arcpy.Sort_management("LIDAR_POINTS", "../high_points.shp", "Z DESCENDING")
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management("high_points", "PGON_ID")
arcpy.Sort_management("LIDAR_POINTS", "../low_points.shp", "Z ASCENDING")
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management("low_points", "PGON_ID")
arcpy.Merge_management("high_points;low_points", "../pairs.shp")
arcpy.PointsToLine_management("pairs","../lines.shp","PGON_ID")
```

RESULT shows original points labelled by Z:

[image]

Note: it is very fast but won't handle duplicated extreme points, it will pick first ones.

Comment: I definitely agree that points 2 and 3 have a higher slope than 1 and 4.  I believe you are correct in that using the word "maximum" is not appropriate.  I suppose what I'm really after is the slope between the maximum elevation and the minimum elevation for a give area.  When/if there are multiple identical max/min values within the area, I want to choose the pair with the furthest distance.  I apologize if I wasn't clear.  Thank you for the explanation above.

Comment: I think I will change the word "maximum" in the OP.

Comment: Now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

After a while of messing around with this I came up with a workflow that works.  It is not the fastest and I'm sure could be improved.  I don't want to accept this answer yet in case someone has anything to add.  The general workflow is the following:

For each input polygon:

- extract the portion of the raster that falls beneath the polygon
- convert the extracted raster to points
- get the min and max value of all points
- find the min/max pair with the greatest distance between them
- calculate slope, angle of incline, max difference, etc.
- insert a new polygon that contains all of the new stat data

Here is the fully commented script:

```
import arcpy, os, math

#Input tool parameters
inPads = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
dem = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

#create empty fc for the results to be stored in
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outPath, outName, "POLYGON", "", "", "", arcpy.Describe(inPads).spatialReference)

sr = arcpy.Describe(inPads).spatialReference
srDEM = arcpy.Describe(dem).spatialReference

if sr.linearUnitName != srDEM.linearUnitName:
    arcpy.AddError("Linear Units of Input Spatial References Do Not Match! If the linear units don't fit, I must aquit!!!  Goodbye...")
else:
    arcpy.AddWarning("Spatial Reference Check Passed...  You may proceed!")

#add necessary fields to the new empty FC
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MAX_X_COORD","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MAX_Y_COORD","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MIN_X_COORD","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MIN_Y_COORD","DOUBLE")

arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MAX_ELEV","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MIN_ELEV","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MAX_CHANGE","DOUBLE")

arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "DIST","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "INCLN_ANGLE","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "MAX_SLOPE","DOUBLE")

arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "ORIG_OID","LONG")

arcpy.AddMessage("Max Elevation Change Calculation Starting For: " + str(inPads))
arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

#SQL query constructor
def buildWhereClauseFromList(table, field, valueList):
    """Takes a list of values and constructs a SQL WHERE
    clause to select those values within a given field and table."""

    # Add DBMS-specific field delimiters
    fieldDelimited = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.Describe(table).path, field)

    # Determine field type
    fieldType = arcpy.ListFields(table, field)[0].type

    # Add single-quotes for string field values
    if str(fieldType) == 'String':
        valueList = ["'%s'" % value for value in valueList]

    # Format WHERE clause in the form of an IN statement
    whereClause = "%s IN(%s)" % (fieldDelimited, ', '.join(map(str, valueList)))
    return whereClause

#list for data that needs to be eliminated after the tool runs.
deleteList = []    

#turn the input polys into an "in memory layer"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inPads, 'pads_lyr')

arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

#Set a count int
id = 0

#Basic arcpy.da search cursor implementation to cycle through each feature in the original poly fc
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('pads_lyr', ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        #construction of a where clause to actually select each row for further geo-processing
        where = buildWhereClauseFromList('pads_lyr', "OBJECTID", [row[0]])

        #clear current selection - prob not necessary, but why not...
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('pads_lyr', "CLEAR_SELECTION")

        #make a row selection based on the current OID used to construct the where clause (SQL)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('pads_lyr', "NEW_SELECTION", where)

        #copy the selected poly feature to a temporary fc that contains only obe feature.
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('pads_lyr', os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPad' + str(id)))

        #clip the portion of the dem that falls under the geometry of the current row
        arcpy.Clip_management(dem, "", os.path.join(outPath, 'tempRast' + str(id)), os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPad' + str(id)), "", "ClippingGeometry")

    #clear current selection - again, prob not necessary...
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('pads_lyr', "CLEAR_SELECTION")

    #convert the raster cells to points with values
        arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempRast' + str(id)), os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPoints' + str(id)))

    #Get XY
    arcpy.AddXY_management(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPoints' + str(id)))

    #Get min and max values from point features
        min = arcpy.SearchCursor(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPoints' + str(id)), "", "", "", "grid_code" + " A").next().getValue("grid_code")  
        max = arcpy.SearchCursor(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPoints' + str(id)), "", "", "", "grid_code" + " D").next().getValue("grid_code")

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPoints' + str(id)), 'points_lyr')

    whereMax = buildWhereClauseFromList('points_lyr', "grid_code", [max])
    whereMin = buildWhereClauseFromList('points_lyr', "grid_code", [min])

        maxCoords = []
        minCoords = []

        minPoint = "NULL"
    maxPoint = "NULL"

    #start tie breaking distance, this gets recycled later as the result becomes the greatest excepted distance
    dist = 0.0

        #Select all of the points with the maxValue and append their coordinates to the coordinate list
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('points_lyr', "NEW_SELECTION", whereMax)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('points_lyr', ["POINT_X", "POINT_Y"]) as tCurs:
            for r in tCurs:
                maxCoords.append([r[0], r[1]])

        #Select all of the points with the minValue and append their coordinates to the coordinate list     
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('points_lyr', "NEW_SELECTION", whereMin)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('points_lyr', ["POINT_X", "POINT_Y"]) as tCurs:
            for r in tCurs:
                minCoords.append([r[0], r[1]])

    #In case of multiple points with the same min or max values, use the largest distanced coordinates  
    for maxCoord in maxCoords:
            maxGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(maxCoord[0], maxCoord[1]), sr)
        for minCoord in minCoords:
            minGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(minCoord[0], minCoord[1]), sr)

                if minGeom.distanceTo(maxGeom) > dist:
                    dist = minGeom.distanceTo(maxGeom)
                    minPoint = minGeom
                    maxPoint = maxGeom

    arcpy.AddMessage("Excepted Coordinates: " + "MaxValuePoint(" + str(maxPoint.firstPoint.X) + ", " + str(maxPoint.firstPoint.Y) + ")  MinValuePoint(" + str(minPoint.firstPoint.X) + ", " + str(minPoint.firstPoint.Y) + ")")

    #get the difference of the min and max..  Min and Max never change even if a further distanced pair is selected from tie breaking
        diff = float(max - min)

    #get slope value for max and min points
    slope = float(diff/dist) 

    #get angle of incliniation ----> Using simple trig inverser tangent, we know that tan(angle) = rise/run.
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan((diff/dist)))    

    #construct a "data access" inserter for the new result FC and all the necessary fields
        inserter = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(outPath, outName), ["SHAPE@", "MAX_ELEV", "MIN_ELEV" ,"MAX_CHANGE", "MAX_X_COORD", "MAX_Y_COORD", "MIN_X_COORD", "MIN_Y_COORD", "DIST", "MAX_SLOPE", "INCLN_ANGLE", "ORIG_OID"])

    #use the new inserter to insert a new row ( note:  the shape@ token gets passed directly from the original search cursor...  is this a no, no, i.e. nested cursors? - john davies)
        inserter.insertRow([row[1], max, min, diff, maxPoint.firstPoint.X, maxPoint.firstPoint.Y, minPoint.firstPoint.X, minPoint.firstPoint.Y, dist, slope, angle, row[0]])

    #delete the inserter from RAM
    del inserter

        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
        arcpy.AddMessage("Feature Added ID: " + str(id))
        arcpy.AddMessage("                                         max/min elevation difference: " + str(diff))
        arcpy.AddMessage("                                                     max/min distance: " + str(dist))
        arcpy.AddMessage("                                                                slope: " + str(slope))
        arcpy.AddMessage("                                                              incline: " + str(angle))


        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

    #append the delete list with all temp data from this iteration
        deleteList.append(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPoints' + str(id)))
        deleteList.append(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempRast' + str(id)))
        deleteList.append(os.path.join(outPath, 'tempPad' + str(id)))
    #delete "in mem" layer
    arcpy.Delete_management('points_lyr')

    #up that counter
    id = id + 1

arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
arcpy.AddMessage("All Features have been Calculated...  Gotta clean up a bit... this might take a second, or two, or three...  maybe a lot more...")
arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
arcpy.AddMessage("...Cleaning Up")
arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

#join the original poly FCs data back to the new result FC (in case there are any fields that should be preserved)
arcpy.JoinField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "ORIG_OID", inPads, "OBJECTID")

#cleanup everything in the delete list
for item in deleteList:
    arcpy.Delete_management(item)

#cleanup some uneccesary fields
arcpy.DeleteField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "ORIG_OID")

#cleanup more uneccesary fields
try:
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "SHAPE_Length_1")
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
    #WHy cant delete these fields???
    arcpy.AddWarning("An expected cleanup field 'SHAPE_Length_1' wasn't found...  Everything is probably okay, but check your results.")

try:
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(os.path.join(outPath, outName), "SHAPE_Area_1")
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
    arcpy.AddWarning("An expected cleanup field 'SHAPE_Length_1' wasn't found...  Everything is probably okay, but check your results.")

arcpy.AddMessage("All Done!")
arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
```

This works really well.  Again, the downfall is how long it takes to run if there are many polygons.

Comment: I'd do a `raster to point` and then a `spatial join` between the points and the polygons for the entire raster and polygon. Don't do it for each feature.